Why can't I get two overhead door opener remotes to both work?
I have a 1/2HP Craftsman garage door opener with a remote keypad and remote in-car button connected to it. The keypad failed so I purchased a replacement.
Following instructions with new keypad - I programmed it and it worked no problem. But when I went to use my car remote button - it would not work. I have gone back and forth deleting codes - re-entering codes for both and it seems like I can only have either the car connected or have the keypad connected -- but not both. What's wrong?

You must be following the wrong procedure and clearing all codes when pairing the second device. Please revise to tell us more about that.

More info .Craftsman 1/2 hp .. Part No: 41A 5483-2. I went back and cleared everything - all codes on opener and keypad. Started first with entering Car - No problem. Set up keypad for correct freq. and went to set up code with opener and opener would not accept it ?? OK - so cleared all codes on opener and keypad again - reset Freq. on keypad and code ... entered keypad first into opener and all good, so second I tried to enter car code and opener would not accept it. Still I can only do one or the other -- not both !! ?? What the heck ?? any ideas or suggestions  ?? Thanks Barry

Please revise to add that information to your question post. It doesn't belong down here. See [ask] and take the [tour].
